# How do I use an operand contained in a PySpark dataframe within a calculation?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that contains operands (specifically greater than, less than, etc).  I want to use those operands to calculate a result using other values in the dataframe and create a new column with this new data.  For instance:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, when

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=1, value=3.0, operand='>', threshold=2. ),
    Row(id=2, value=2.3, operand='>=', threshold=3. ),
    Row(id=3, value=0.0, operand='==', threshold=0.0 )
])

df = df.withColumn('result', when(expr("value " + df.operand + " threshold"), True).otherwise(False))

df.show()
```

I would expect the following result:

```
|id|value|operand|threshold|result|
|--|-----|-------|---------|------|
|1 |  3.0|      >|      2.0|  true|
|2 |  2.3|     >=|      3.0| false|
|3 |  0.0|     ==|      0.0|  true|
```

But instead get the error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.  I have tried different mechanisms of extracting the operand value (i.e. `col("operand")`) but without success.

NB - I appreciate using `==` to determine if doubles are equal is not always reliable, but the use case allows it.

Comment: @obaskly earlier suggested an answer with an UDF that used an if statement, which although not as pithy as arudsekaberne was still a nice alternative.  Can I ask why you deleted it?  Was it wrong in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my dynamic solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

dynamic_condition_udf = udf(lambda value, operand, threshold: eval(f"{value} {operand} {threshold}"))

df.withColumn("result", dynamic_condition_udf("value", "operand", "threshold")).show()
```

Output

```
+---+-----+-------+---------+------+
| id|value|operand|threshold|result|
+---+-----+-------+---------+------+
|  1|  3.0|      >|      2.0|  true|
|  2|  2.3|     >=|      3.0| false|
|  3|  0.0|     ==|      0.0|  true|
+---+-----+-------+---------+------+
```